# Count Elements SubDocument that match a given criterion

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have the following document structure in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "first_name" : "Lorem",
    "last_name" : "Ipsum",
    "conversations" : {
            "personal" : [
                    {
                            "last_message" : "Hello bar",
                            "last_read" : 1474456404
                    },
                     {
                            "last_message" : "Hello foo",
                            "last_read" : 1474456404
                    },
                    ...
            ],

            "group" : [
                    {
                            "last_message" : "Hello Everyone",
                            "last_read" : null
                    }
                    ...
            ]
    }
}
```

I want to count the number of conversations from  the sub arrays, `personal` and `group` where the `last_read` is null, for a given user. Please how can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
db.messages.aggregate(
   [
    { $match: {"_id":"123", 'conversations.$.last_read': null }},
      {
         $group: {
            {$size: "$conversations.personal"}, {$size: "$conversations.group"}
         }
      }
   ]
);
```

but didn't get he desired output. Any better ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query counts the number of sub documents under `personal` and `group` arrays that have `last_read` value `null`.

`$concatArrays` combines multiple arrays into a single one. It was introduced in MongoDB 3.2.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
                        { "$match": {"_id":"123", 'conversations.$.last_read': null }},
                        { "$project":{"messages":{$concatArrays : ["$conversations.personal","$conversations.group"]}}}, 
                        { "$unwind": "$messages"}, {$match:{"messages.last_read": null}}, 
                        { "$group":{"_id":null, count: {$sum:1}}}
                ])
```

Sample Result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per question it looks like you want to find out where `group array last_read` contains `null`. For this you use `$in` in aggregation and then `unwind` `personal` array and count the array. Check bellow aggregation query

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$match": {
        "conversations.group.last_read": {
            "$in": [null]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$conversations.personal"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "personalArrayCount": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
})
```